# how to recover original data from differences btw list elements

Tags: python

I am trying to get the differences between the elements of a list. And then with this difference_list want to have it back.

```
data = [2,4,6,9]
string_diff = []

string = [data[0]]

def diff(x):
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        diff = x[i] - x[i+1]
        string_diff.append(diff)
    return string_diff
print diff(data)
```

output is

```
[-2,-2,-3]
```

I made a new dictionary "string" which already have the first value of the original data. My idea is to create a list which iterates through a loop and also updates parallel so that I can achieve what I want. But I am getting error "List index out of range"

```
def recover(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        r = string[i] - x[i] 
        string.append(r)
    return string    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/file.py", line 28, in <module>
    print recover(string_diff)
  File "C:/Users/file.py", line 23, in recover
    r = string[i] - x[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback as well as correct the indentation (second piece of code seems to have wrong indentation) ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def diff(lst):
    """Return the differences between the items in lst."""
    return [curr - prev for prev, curr in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
```

In use:

```
>>> diff([2, 4, 6, 9])
[-2, -2, -3]
```

Note that this function only uses its explicit parameter, `lst`, rather than relying on scoping to access `string_diff` as your current attempt does. If `lst` will be long, consider using `itertools` - the `izip` and `islice` functions can be used to avoid building the lists all at once.

---

You can also `recover` with only explicit parameters, by passing the `start`:

```
 def recover(diffs, start):
    """Recover the original list from start item and diffs."""
    return [start - sum(diffs[:index]) for index in range(len(diffs) + 1)]
```

In use:

```
>>> recover([-2, -2, -3], 2)
[2, 4, 6, 9]
```

Comment: There is a typo in return [start - sum(diffs[:index]) for index in range(len(diffs) + 1)]

Answer (score 1):

You should somehow remember the first item in the list (which is `2` in this case) as we need it later when recovering from `diffs`. I'd prefer holding that as the first element in the resulting list.

You can use `enumerate()` to iterate over the list and skip *0th* index:

```
>>> data = [2, 4, 6, 9]
>>> string_diff = [data[0]]

>>> for i, ele in enumerate(data[1:], 1):
...     string_diff.append(data[i - 1] - ele)
[2, -2, -2, -3]
```

If you want to get your original list back, you should do exactly the opposite thing by replacing two lists:

```
>>> data = [string_diff[0]]
>>> for i, ele in enumerate(string_diff[1:], 1):
...     data.append(data[i - 1] - ele)
[2, 4, 6, 9]
```